# No space at the begining of Android Gallery in XML

Tags: android, android-layout

Trying to do a simple thing with the Gallery component(default provided by the System). I can display images but despite my struggle to show the gallery without a padding/margin left...so that i can see the gallery on the entire width of the screen it does not work.

This is my code:

```
         <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/screenshotRow"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:padding="0dp" >

                <Gallery
                    android:id="@+id/screenshotGallery"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:spacing="3dip"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
            </TableRow>
```

I don't understand why this is not working. I have searched on google as well, and found this problem occurrence but don't understand what is the solution. A lot of people suggest a horizontal scrollable list..

Is it possible to get rid of the space at the beginning of an android gallery component?
Thank you.

Comment: and hope we can accept answer here ;))

Answer (score 1):

1. Gallery is **deprecated component**. You should use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) (which is part of support library) or similar component instead.
2. "fill_parent" for android:layout_width is deprecated parameter. Use **match_parent** instead
3. I don't get this "despite my struggle to show the gallery without a padding/margin" and then in code you set margin_bottom to 10dp, horizontalSpacing to 5dp, verticalSpacing to 5dp, spacing to 3dp?!? There is your space problem. o.O
4. not sure why u want Gallery in one row!?! Rows should be used inside table, now like this. Gallery inside Relative layout will display it on a full screen. That is how it should be done. Because of strange formatting error on stackoverflow I am sharing you [Gallery inside RelativeLayout xml code here](http://pastebin.com/VnY8KGXf)

   ```
   <Gallery
       android:id="@+id/screenshotGallery"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   ```

hope this helped you ;) Cheers

Comment: not actually true, cause ViewPager (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) is part of support library. I edited main answer so you have link to that component as well. You can find simple example in ApiDemos to see how to use it. ;)